# Resolving TypeScript/TypeORM Error (not assignable to parameter of type '_QueryDeepPartialEntity<T>') with JSONB Column and Record<string, unknown>

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

Context:

I encountered a TypeScript type assignment error in my project using TypeORM, specifically after adding a jsonb column with the type `Record<string, unknown>` to my `WaitlistAction` entity. This error was affecting a transactional update method for a different entity.

Error:

```
@/backend:test:     resolver/form.resolver.ts:766:40 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'FormResponseItem' is not assignable to parameter of type '_QueryDeepPartialEntity<FormResponseItem>'.
@/backend:test:       Types of property 'formResponse' are incompatible.
@/backend:test:         Type 'FormResponse' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | _QueryDeepPartialEntity<FormResponse> | undefined'.
@/backend:test:           Type 'FormResponse' is not assignable to type '_QueryDeepPartialEntity<FormResponse>'.
@/backend:test:             Types of property 'form' are incompatible.
@/backend:test:               Type 'Form' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | _QueryDeepPartialEntity<Form> | undefined'.
@/backend:test:                 Type 'Form' is not assignable to type '_QueryDeepPartialEntity<Form>'.
@/backend:test:                   Types of property 'responses' are incompatible.
@/backend:test:                     Type 'FormResponse[]' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | _QueryDeepPartialEntity<FormResponse>[] | undefined'.
@/backend:test: 
@/backend:test:     766               .update({ id: item.id }, item);
```

New column addition on the `WaitlistAction` entity:

```
@Column({
  type: "jsonb",
  nullable: true,
})
@Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
public metadata?: Record<string, unknown>;
```

What's strange is that my db migration file will still be generated correctly by TypeORM, but when I run my tests, these unrelated test errors on different entities (`FormResponse`, `FormResponseItem`) will be affected.

Only by methodically commenting out parts of my pull request, I pinpointed that the addition of the jsonb column on the `WaitlistAction` table was the trigger for this error.

It seems like there is a mismatch in the expected types by TypeORM's update method and the actual type of the entity.

How can I resolve this type assignment error in TypeScript when using TypeORM, especially considering the complex nature of JSONB columns and nested entity types? Is there a specific pattern or type definition that should be used to ensure compatibility?

How does changing the column type from Record<string, unknown> to Record<string, any> in TypeScript/TypeORM resolve the type assignment error with JSONB columns, and what are the implications of this approach in terms of type safety and best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the column type from `Record<string, unknown>` to `Record<string, any>` resolved the issue.

Before:

```
  @Column({
    type: "jsonb",
    nullable: true,
  })
  @Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
  public metadata?: Record<string, unknown>;
```

After:

```
  @Column({
    type: "jsonb",
    nullable: true,
  })
  @Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
  public metadata?: Record<string, any>;
```

The reason why this might work is that `unknown` is more restrictive than `any` in Typescript. While `unknown` ensures type safety by requiring type assertions, `any` bypasses these checks and allows any operation.

In TypeORM, the type declaration helps infer the handling of database data. `Record<string, unknown>` implies the values are unknown, thus restricting operations. `Record<string, any>` removes these restrictions, making the object more flexible.

The error was due to a mismatch in expected types. Using `any` eliminates the type barriers, resolving the incompatibility.

While `any` resolves the issue, it reduces type safety, potentially hiding other issues.

Changing the type to `Record<string, any>` addresses the type assignment issue by allowing more flexible operations on the metadata field. This change is significant for JSONB columns in TypeORM, as it influences how the library handles data read/write operations. The key here is the trade-off between type safety and flexibility. While `any` solves the immediate type mismatch problem, it can lead to less predictable code and potentially hide bugs that would be caught by TypeScript's type system.

For next steps, it'd be really awesome if TypeORM were better at catching these issues earlier / more upstream.